# pandas delete the 0 appears most times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
a   b   c   d
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   7
5   2   0   4
6   3   0   0
0   0   8   8
0   7   7   7
0   0   0   1
```

1: fow each row, if the counts of 0 is >90% of the column counts(in this case: mean: 0.9*4 ), then delete the row.

2: fow each column, if the counts of 0 is >90% of the row counts(in this case: mean: 0.9*7 ), then delete the column.

Comment: What is difference with your last [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38094638/2901002)? Only constants?

Comment: What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like:

```
mask_rows = pd.DataFrame.sum(df == 0, axis=1) > 0.9*len(df.columns)
mask_cols = pd.DataFrame.sum(df == 0, axis=0) > 0.9*len(df.columns)
```

This creates mask following my interpretation of your question...

Answer (score 0):

First create a mask that reveals the place zeros are:

```
df_temp = (df == 0)
```

Then drop the lines:

```
df.drop(df_temp.mean(axis = 1) > 0.9,inplace = True)
```

And finally the columns:

```
df.drop(df_temp.mean() > 0.9, 1, inplace = True)
```